# how to create mock or fake HttpContext.Current.Application for doing Nunit testing of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, nunit

We have an already developed ASP.NET MVC application. We are told to write Unit test case using NUnit.

This is how the application in developed.

1) In the  `Session_Start` in the *Global.asax* we hitting a database and fetching some lookup values from database and putting it in

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["lookup"]=(dbvalues);
```

2) In the  ActionMethods of the controller  and in some other classes validation methods we are fetching the values from the `Application["lookup"]` .

we are assigning the `Application["lookup"]` to `Viewbag` and that will be used to list values in the view.

For example : List of store we will put into `Application["lookup"]` and in the `Index` method of the controller we are assigning the `ViewBag.Stores =Application["lookup"]`.

Now we are told to write Nunit test cases for each and every controller methods.

We created fake or mock `HttpContext` but the issue is with `Httpcontext.current.Application`.

For example we created the `Httpcontext.Current.Application["lookup"]="values"`  in the Nunit test methods but `Application["lookup"]` is no there when it hits the controller `Index` method. Please help how to create fake `Httpcontext.current.Application["lookup"]`

Comment: Why are you using `Application`? Why not use dependency injection? It will be far easier to mock.

Comment: HttpContext makes unit testing difficult. abstract out the functionality you need and inject/resolve that where needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any HttpContext directly, instead write a wrapper around the functionality that you use so that you can mock it easily.

For **example** in your current case for the lookup data you would need to create an interface that will wrap around the logic to extract that data.

```
public interface IApplicationDataHelper
{
    LookupData GetApplicationLookupData();
}
```

Your class that you would be using is going to look like :

```
class ApplicationDataHelper
{
    LookupData GetApplicationLookupData()
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Application["lookup"];
    }
}
```

(Please name the classes and interfaces accordingly to the data they provide, this is just an example).

I have simplified it, but this is the idea. Now every controller/class that you have will depend on *IApplicationDataHelper* and not directly on the static *HttpContext*. In your tests you will mock *IApplicationDataHelper*  to return whatever you want.

This is general approach for such situations, the resultant code would be more maintainable as well.

There is a reason why unit tests should be written before the code, extracting the decencies might take a lot of time if the code is already in place...

Comment: Please provide some code or idea

Comment: I have added an example. In case it is still not clear - you should read on unit testing and DI in general. It is important that you split out responsibilities to different classes